# Openshift templates with array parameters

Tags: openshift

I am trying to create an Openshift template for a Job that passes the job's command line arguments in a template parameter using the following template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: test-template
objects:
  - apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
    kind: Job
    metadata:
      name: "${JOB_NAME}"
    spec:
      parallelism: 1
      completions: 1
      autoSelector: true
      template:
        metadata:
          name: "${JOB_NAME}"
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: "app"
              image: "batch-poc/sample-job:latest"
              args: "${{JOB_ARGS}}"
parameters:
  - name: JOB_NAME
    description: "Job Name"
    required: true
  - name: JOB_ARGS
    description: "Job command line parameters"
```

Because the 'args' need to be an array, I am trying to set the template parameter using JSON syntax, e.g. from the command line:

```
oc process -o=yaml test-template -v=JOB_NAME=myjob,JOB_ARGS='["A","B"]'
```

or programmatically through the Spring Cloud Launcher OpenShift Client:

```
OpenShiftClient client;
Map<String,String> templateParameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
templateParameters.put("JOB_NAME", jobId);
templateParameters.put("JOB_ARGS", "[ \"A\", \"B\", \"C\" ]");
KubernetesList processed = client.templates()
   .inNamespace(client.getNamespace())
   .withName("test-template")
   .process(templateParameters);
```

In both cases, it seems to fail because Openshift is interpreting the comma after the first array element as a delimiter and not parsing the remainder of the string.

The `oc process` command sets the parameter value to '["A"' and reports an error: "invalid parameter assignment in "test-template": "\"B\"]"".

The Java version throws an exception:

> ```
>           Error executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/oapi/v1/namespaces/batch-poc/templates/test-template. Cause: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: io.fabric8.openshift.api.model.Template[\"objects\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Job[\"spec\"]->io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.JobSpec[\"template\"]->io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.PodTemplateSpec[\"spec\"]->io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.PodSpec[\"containers\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Container[\"args\"])
> ```

I believe this is due to a [known Openshift issue](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/9565).

I was wondering if anyone has a workaround or an alternative way of setting the job's parameters?

Interestingly, if I go to the OpenShift web console, click 'Add to Project' and choose test-template, it prompts me to enter a value for the JOB_ARGS parameter.  If I enter a literal JSON array there, it works, so I figure there must be a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: What version of OpenShift oc client are you using? There was an issue with how older ``oc`` versions parsed values with embedded commas and other special characters. Also, have you tried using separate ``--param`` option for each parameter (I think ``-v`` must be deprecated as not in help string)? Finally, it probably will not help anyway, as don't believe it can be a JSON snippet. It should just take the whole thing as a string.

Comment: Oh wait, you are using new ``${{}}`` form. I thought that was restricted to literal values and wasn't an arbitrary JSON snippet.

Comment: `oc version` shows oc v3.1.0.4.

Per the [Openshift Template docs](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/dev_guide/templates.html#templates-parameters)
> Parameters can be a json/yaml value by placing values in the form ${{PARAMETER_NAME}} in place of any field in the template.

The web console correctly parses parameters as JSON, so it is allowed in templates.  I just can't figure out how to pass array values because of the comma issue described above.

I did some debugging to try to figure out how the openshift client does it, and it looks like it processes the template on the client.

Comment: Did you try separate arguments. Ie., ``--param JOB_NAME=myjob --param JOB_ARGS='["A","B"]'``

Comment: What is the server side version of OpenShift? That ``${{}}`` syntax, and fixes in parsing of arguments, was I thought only fixed in more recent ``oc`` version than you have.

Answer (score 5):

We worked out how to do it; template snippet:

```
    spec:
    securityContext:
     supplementalGroups: "${{SUPPLEMENTAL_GROUPS}}"
parameters:
- description: Supplemental linux groups
  name: SUPPLEMENTAL_GROUPS
  value: "[14051, 14052, 48, 65533, 9050]"
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the `value` must be valid json.  So if your list is string data (instead of numeric) then you need to ensure proper quoting.  This will recognize the value as a list `'["foo", "bar"]'`, but this will recognize the value as a string `"['foo', 'bar']"`

Comment: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/dev_guide/templates.html

  The resulting value will be unquoted unless, after substitution is performed, the  result is not a valid json object. If the result is not a valid json value, the resulting value will be quoted and treated as a standard string.

Comment: @Lucas - single quotes don't seem to work at all for me. It only works if I use double quotes around the string values, which means I have to additionally escape them with backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we have 3 files :
- environment configuration,
- template yaml
- sh file which run oc process.

And working case looks like this :

environment file :

```
#-- CORS  ---------------------------------------------------------
cors_origins='["*"]'
cors_acceptable_headers='["*","Authorization"]'
```

template yaml :

```
- apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
  kind: KongPlugin
  metadata:
    name: plugin-common-cors
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: ${ingress_class}
  config:
    origins: "${{origins}}"
    headers: "${{acceptable_headers}}"
    credentials: true
    max_age: 3600
  plugin: cors
```

sh file running oc :

```
if [ -f templates/kong-plugins-template.yaml ]; then
    echo "++ Applying Global Plugin Template ..."
    oc process -f templates/kong-plugins-template.yaml \
      -p ingress_class="${kong_ingress_class}" \
      -p origins=${cors_origins} \
      -p acceptable_headers=${cors_acceptable_headers} \
      -p request_per_second=${kong_throttling_request_per_second:-100} \
      -p request_per_minute=${kong_throttling_request_per_minute:-2000} \
      -p rate_limit_by="${kong_throttling_limit_by:-ip}" \
      -o yaml \
      > yaml.tmp && \
    cat yaml.tmp | oc $param_mode -f -
    [ $? -ne 0 ] && [ "$param_mode" != "delete" ] && exit 1
    rm -f *.tmp
fi
```

The sh file should read environment file.